# Merge two lists of dictionaries by params in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, aggregate

I have 2 lists of dictionaries with impressions data and clicks data. For example:

> [{'offerId': '1650', 'position': '15', 'clicksCount': 21}, {'offerId':
>   '2323', 'position': '12', 'clicksCount': 14}, {'offerId': '2323',
>   'position': '14', 'clicksCount': 8}, {'offerId': '1621', 'position':
>   '10', 'clicksCount': 7}]...
>
> [{'offerId': '3207', 'position': '9', 'impressionsCount': 866},
>   {'offerId': '1650', 'position': '6', 'impressionsCount': 896},
>   {'offerId': '3207', 'position': '1', 'impressionsCount': 909},
>   {'offerId': '2323', 'position': '12'}]...

I need to merge it together and by offerId and position to get results (clicks and impressions) for each offer position.

To make something like that
[image]

I'm tried this code, but it's returned wrong results:

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in (clicks_aggregated_data, impressions_aggregated_data):
    for elem in l:
        d[elem['offerId']].update(elem)
        d[elem['position']].update(elem)
combined_data = list(d.values())


for model, group in groupby(combined_data, key=lambda x:x['offerId']):
    print(list(group))
```

Can someone help me to achieve result like in a table (screenshot)?

Comment: if data is incomplete or as a picture, we cannot recreate. can you update?

Comment: why is offerid repeated? how are your combining clicks and expressions, that table doens't help much, it's better if you can provide a more clear output with explanation instead of us doing the guesswork

Comment: If you're using pandas, you could convert to dataframe and then merge `pd.DataFrame(d1).merge(pd.DataFrame(d2), on=['offerId', 'position'])`

Comment: sounds like you just want to throw this in a dataframe and then order it? technically just appending data

Comment: offerId repeated because offer card can show on different position i need to understand how many impressions for each offer on each position and how many clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a lookup dict from `impressions_aggregated_data` and then do the merge.

**Ex:**

```
impressions_aggregated_data_lookup = {"{}_{}".format(i["offerId"], i["position"]) : i["impressionsCount"] for i in impressions_aggregated_data}

for i in clicks_aggregated_data:
    if "{}_{}".format(i["offerId"], i["position"]) in impressions_aggregated_data_lookup:
        i.update({"impressionsCount": impressions_aggregated_data_lookup["{}_{}".format(i["offerId"], i["position"])]})

pprint(clicks_aggregated_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping this is what you want to do. create `pandas dataframe` with the two dicts and then find the sum of the `clicks` and `impressions`. See a mockup below. Let me know if it works.

```
import pandas as pd

d1=[{'offerId': '1650', 'position': '15', 'clicksCount': 21}, 
 {'offerId': '2323', 'position': '12', 'clicksCount': 14}, 
 {'offerId': '2323', 'position': '14', 'clicksCount': 8}, 
 {'offerId': '1621', 'position': '10', 'clicksCount': 7}]

d2=[{'offerId': '3207', 'position': '9', 'impressionsCount': 866},
 {'offerId': '1650', 'position': '6', 'impressionsCount': 896}, 
 {'offerId': '3207', 'position': '1', 'impressionsCount': 909}, 
 {'offerId': '2323', 'position': '12'}]

combdf=df1.append([pd.DataFrame(d1), pd.DataFrame(d2)],sort=False)

combdf.groupby(['offerId', 'position']).sum()[["clicksCount", "impressionsCount"]].reset_index()
```

Result below:

```
offerId position    clicksCount impressionsCount
0   1621    10  14.0    0.0
1   1650    15  42.0    0.0
2   1650    6   0.0 896.0
3   2323    12  28.0    0.0
4   2323    14  16.0    0.0
5   3207    1   0.0 909.0
6   3207    9   0.0 866.0
```